# VSFTP chroot_local_user doesn't work

Tags: ftp, vsftpd

VSFTP is set up and I want users not to go into other directories then their /home. I've set:

```
chroot_local_user=YES
```

But it doesn't seem to work (after restarting).

Could it be that I have the wrong config file? Or is there other settings or ways of logging in that skip this config line?

---

**Edit**: Together with someone else I found that the vsftp was not at all the server listening to the port.. Therefor, I didn't see my changes reflected. Solved the problem somewhere else thus.

Still, the answers below might solve the problem for others who have this.

Comment: Jailing the User to it's home dir does not work, when using SFTP. Seems to be a bug.

Comment: Vsftpd is garbage. I've wasted hours trying to configure it. Just use proftpd instead. It even has an optional gui component that simplifies these kinds of setup issues.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have the `chroot_list_enable` option enabled? If so, any users listed in `chroot_list_file` will *not* be chrooted.

Answer (score 0):

I think part of this is redundant, but I've not gone back to poke at it, since it works.  (I think I was where you were when first setting this up, which is why chroot_local_user is set...)

```
# You may specify an explicit list of local users to chroot() to their home
# directory. If chroot_local_user is YES, then this list becomes a list of
# users to NOT chroot().
chroot_list_enable=YES
chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list
chroot_local_user=YES
userlist_enable=YES
```

...and /etc/vsftpd.chroot_list is an empty file.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure user's home directory is set and correct (not /root):

```
usermod -d /home/user user
```